# Cannot show waiting message while long operation is running in Mono for Android

Tags: c#, android, mono

I'm trying to show a waiting message via a Toast while a long operation is running. I'm using a BackgroundWorker.
This code is inside a ListView_ItemClick event handler:

```
var bgWait = new BackgroundWorker();
bgWait.DoWork += bgWait_DoWork;
bgWait.RunWorkerAsync();
bgWait.RunWorkerCompleted += bgWait_Completed;
```

The code in bgWait_DoWork event handler is the following:

```
private void bgWait_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
var toastWait = Toast.MakeText(this, "Please wait", ToastLength.Long);
toastWait.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Top & GravityFlags.Center, 0, 0);
toastWait.Show();
TimeConsumingOperation();
toastWait.Cancel();
}
```

When I run in debug mode, it seems that only the first line from bgWait_DoWork is reached - "var toastWait = Toast.MakeText(this, "Please wait", ToastLength.Long);" - and then it jumps to bgWait_Completed event handler.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: I get an error related to the fact that the bgWait_DoWork is not completed. In the bgWait_Completed I'm using a result from bgWait_DoWork, so the error is right to happen.

Comment: well, post the related stack trace (or whatever it is called in mono), will you?

Comment: This is the exception message I get on the first line in bgWait_DoWork: LocalizedMessage = "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare (not the same language, but same issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling UI-related API from a secondary thread (bgWait_DoWork is executed on a secondary thread).

You must instead do something like this:

```cs
private void bgWait_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Toast toastWait = null;
    RunOnUIThread (() => 
    {
        toastWait = Toast.MakeText(this, "Please wait", ToastLength.Long);
        toastWait.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Top & GravityFlags.Center, 0, 0);
        toastWait.Show();
    });
    TimeConsumingOperation();
    RunOnUIThread (() =>
    {
        toastWait.Cancel(); 
    });
}
```

}